# Is it possible to run a proxy server in an iOS app, to be called from WKWebview?

Tags: ios, webview, proxy, wkwebview

The current setup is a single-page Javascript+HTML application (SPA) and a Node/Express proxy. Both are hosted on a server and used in a WKWebview.

Is it possible to embed this setup inside a native app with WKWebview and skip the external server hosting? Specifically, could [Nodekit](http://nodekit.io/) be used to run a Node proxy on the phone, to be called by the SPA from webview? If not, is there any other way to achieve the same result?

Comment: Are you okay with the Node proxy on the server and the SPA on your device, or does that not help?

Comment: @Crashalot can you please elaborate bit more? I'm interested .

Comment: @Suryakant do you have an ios device? if so, you could run the SPA inside our app for free and distribute to users.

Comment: @Crashalot of-course I have. what is SPA??

Comment: @Suryakant SPA = single-page app. here's the link: https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/couch-productivity/id550950815?mt=8. if you have questions, feel free to email info at panabee dt com

Comment: @Crashalot one of my app is relying on `UIWebView` to browse Websites so far and routing all the traffic from a proxy server is The Main function of my app (I achieve this proxy functionality using NSURLProtocol) but now as you might know Apple has marked UIWebView as deprecated ( [link] (https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiwebview?changes=latest_minor)) now promoting 'WKWebView' from iOS8 and it's far better then UIWebView but there is no way to achieve proxy functionality with WKWebView (as per me). so my question is that if there is a way to achieve Proxy with WKWebView